# Python CVXPY Minimise a Percentile Variable Portfolio Optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, quantile, cvxpy

I have a set of portfolio returns:

```
    total
Scenario    
20160608    -131,225.96
20160609    -3,526,055.32
20160610    -23,529,796.59
20160613    -21,268,638.69
20160614    -10,528,552.12
... ...
20210528    5,643,877.68
20210531    236,667.34
20210601    8,244,154.88
20210602    -2,213,117.88
20210603    4,807,859.21
```

and a set of hedge instruments log returns:

```
        SPY US Equity   EEM US Equity   TLT US Equity   DXY Index   HYG US Equity
Scenario                    
20160608    0.00    0.01    0.01    -0.00   0.00
20160609    -0.00   -0.01   0.01    0.00    -0.00
20160610    -0.01   -0.03   0.00    0.01    -0.00
20160613    -0.01   -0.01   0.00    -0.00   -0.01
20160614    -0.00   -0.00   -0.00   0.01    -0.00
... ... ... ... ... ...
20210528    0.00    0.01    -0.00   0.00    -0.00
20210531    0.00    0.00    0.00    -0.00   0.00
20210601    -0.00   0.02    -0.00   0.00    -0.00
20210602    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
20210603    -0.00   -0.01   -0.00   0.01    -0.00
```

I am using this to calculate a historic VaR, given a specific weighting of those instruments with the portfolio:

```
weights = np.array([-0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5])
var = np.quantile((hedge_returns*weights).sum(axis=1) + port_returns, confidence)
```

I'm trying to run an optimisation to select the best weighting of instruments from the hedge portfolio to generate the minimum value of the var variable.

I tried to use CVXPY to optimise this, however I get this error:
NotImplementedError: Strict inequalities are not allowed.

I believe this is because CVXPY does not have a quantile function.

```
n = 5
confidence = 0.05
weights = cp.Variable(n)

var = np.quantile(((hedge_returns*np.array(weights)).sum(axis=1) + port_returns), confidence)

obj = cp.Minimize(var)

prob = cp.Problem(objective=obj)

prob.solve()  # Returns the optimal value.
print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)
print("optimal var", x.value, y.value)
```

Any ideas for an alternative approach here?

Thanks!

Other idea, sort the resulting matrix, and select the correct interval but sorting I'm struggling with.

```
percentile = 0.05
length = 1302
line = round(percentile * length)

var = np.sort(sum((hedge_returns@weights).T) + port_returns)[line]
```

Comment: Thought about the idea of calculating the line required as a method for getting the percentile, but does not seem like there is a sort method.

var = np.sort(sum((hedge_returns@weights).T) + port_returns)[percentile_row]

However no luck with sorting yet.

Comment: You cannot use a general (black box) function like `np.quantile`  inside CVXPY. Only CVXPY's own functions are allowed (see the documentation). As a general NLP this is also difficult as this thing is non-differentiable. Maybe use a meta-heuristic? (Some related problems like quantile regression can be formulated as LPs).

Comment: maybe can sum top k largest then minus top k-1 largest, where k corresponds to a percentage. Might need some discretization techniques.